# Data set Not referencing correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having a problem with data set. I'm using one to populate text boxes of my form. The user selects a value to search from, they press a button and then the text boxes  are populated. This works fine for the first record but I want to page through them. I've declared a data set to be used by my other methods but when it gets to paging the returned rows I keep getting an Object reference error. Can anyone shed some light on where I'm going wrong?

Declaring Variables:

```
//creates a global dataset for the copies table
DataSet dataSetHM;
//create default row values
int MaxRows = 0;
int inc = 0;
```

The connection to the database and filling the data set:

```
protected void ExecuteSelectCopies(string sName)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    string sql =
        "SELECT tblCopies.CopyID, tblSoftware.SoftwareName, tblCopies.AssetName, tblCopies.Location,"
        + " tblCopies.LicenceKey, tblCopies.OEM, tblCopies.State, tblCopies.InstallationDate"
        + " FROM tblCopies"
        + " INNER JOIN tblSoftware ON tblCopies.SoftwareID = tblSoftware.SoftwareID"
        + " WHERE tblSoftware.SoftwareName = @SoftwareName"
        + " ORDER BY tblCopies.CopyID";
    SqlDataAdapter adapterHM = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand(sql, connectionHM);
    adapter.SelectCommand = select;
    select.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SoftwareName", sName));
    //open the connection
    connectionHM.Open();
    dataSetHM =  new DataSet();
    adapterHM.Fill(dataSetHM, "Copies");
    NavigateCopies();
    MaxRows = dataSetHM.Tables["Copies"].Rows.Count;

    connectionHM.Close();
}
```

The method for filling the text boxes:

```
    private void NavigateCopies()
{
    DataRow dRow = dataSetHM.Tables["Copies"].Rows[inc];
    TextBoxCopyID.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
    TextBoxSoftwareName.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
    DropDownListAssetName.SelectedItem.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
    DropDownListLocation.SelectedItem.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
    TextBoxLicence.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString();
    DropDownListType.SelectedItem.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(5).ToString();
    DropDownListState.SelectedItem.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(6).ToString();
    TextBoxInstall.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(7).ToString();    
}
```

And finally the button for the next record:

```
    protected void ButtonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (inc != MaxRows - 1)
    {
        inc++;
        NavigateCopies();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.show("No more Rows");
    }

}
```

Any help with this would be very much appreciated. I honestly can't understand why the data set works for the navigation method initially but not for the second. I've been using this http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p7.html as a guide, their example displays data on page load where as mine is displayed when a search parameter is selected. I don't know if this is a problem but a bit more information never hurts!

Comment: The difference between what you're doing and what the article shows is that with winforms, objects are kept 'alive' and usable for the duration of the Form whereas for asp.net they are not. Consider using the Session or Cache to persist the object. Consider this article for more detail http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx

Comment: Ok thank you Ric. I guess that would make sense. Would you happen to know of any resources for them?

Comment: Here is an article that goes into detail regarding storing objects in the session: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx It includes reading and saving objects to the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persist the `DataSet` in the Session/Cache/ViewState (which ever one of these is the most applicable solution for you).
That way you can retrieve the `DataSet` between postback's and continue to display the data that is required.

[Here is how to accomplish this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/257001/store-data-set-in-session) (albeit a simple example) and an article that delves into object persistence within asp.net: [asp.net object persistence.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx)

Comment: Fantastic Ric! I'm still learning the ropes with asp's I probably would have carried on struggling without your help! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. Also take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331962/A-Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-ASP-NET-State-Management It seems quite good and provides quite a few ways of storing objects and retrieving them.

Comment: Brilliant. I'll sink my teeth into it now! Thanks again!

Comment: Ah doesn't seem to be working for me. I must be doing it wrong

Comment: in page load, create the dataset as you seem to be doing. once it is populated with data, do something like this Session["MyDataSet"] = myDataSet; When you want to retrieve it: var myDataSet = Session["MyDataSet"] as DataSet;

Comment: Ah no see The user needs to select a search term and press a button. The data set is created after that. Is that a problem?

Comment: No not really, put the code in the button_click event (to populate the dataset) then add to session. You can always overwrite the session data at any point. Then, when you need to page the data, retrieve it from the Session and do the pagination.

Comment: hmm well there's got to be an issue with the session data set being populated or carried over. Its not getting the first returned row let alone all of them.

Comment: well i suppose if the user is first searching then paging, the initial search can add the dataset to the session and the paging would refer to the session dataset to page.

Comment: yeah that's the plan. Its getting the initial output over. Keep getting the object reference is null as if there's nothing in there despite the fact that All the things I need should be there. Not fun.